# select Amount sum by where

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I have two tables, one with WeekNr and OrderNum, one with OrderNum ,Article and ammount

table one

```
WeekNr OrderNum
35     10001                 
35     10003
35     10008
36     10006
36     10005
37     10004
38     10007
39     10002
```

table 2

```
OrderNum  Article    Ammount
10001     A           5   
10001     B           2
10002     A           2
10003     A           1
10003     B           2
10004     A           10
10005     B           1
10007     B           3
```

How do I get a result like

```
Article Total WeekNr35-36, Total WeekNr 37-38, Total WeekNr 39-40
   A         8                  10                   2
   B         5                   3                   0
```

Comment: JOIN the two tables, do GROUP BY, and SUM(case week ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query

```
select b.article,
      sum(case when a.weeknr in (35,36) then b.amount end ) as "Total WeekNr35-36",
      sum(case when a.weeknr in (37,38) then b.amount end ) as "Total WeekNr37-38",
      sum(case when a.weeknr in (39,40) then b.amount end ) as "Total WeekNr39-40"
      from table_one a inner join table_two b 
            on a.ordernum=b.ordernum 
      group by b.article
```

Here the [SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bdd9/19) to check ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Define a period table to make it easier to group your data and for simplicity in case you need to extend the periods later, or if you need to make custom headers. My suggestion:

```
Period, PeriodText, Week
1, 'Weeks 24 and 25', 24
1, 'Weeks 24 and 25', 25
```

Then create a grouped dataset, that you transform using the pivot function

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT O.Article, P.PeriodText, SUM(O.Ammount) AS Ammount
        FROM Orders O
        INNER JOIN Weeks W on O.Week = W.Week
        INNER JOIN Periods P ON P.Week = O.Week
        GROUP BY O.Article, P.PeriodText
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Ammount)
    FOR [Article] IN (
      ['Weeks 24 and 25','Weeks 26 and 27']
    )
) AS PivotTable
```

Also i would suggest merging your two tables, and putting the weeks into the orders table. 
In addition you could insert a order date that you run a week function on.